# Adding/calling/setting Class attributes outside of Class definiton

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, pep

I have seen this coding pattern in codes I am (re)writing:

```
class Outside(object):
    pass

Outside.example = 10.
```

My instinct was that I didn't like it! I'd prefer:

```
class Inside(object):
    example = 10.
```

Are there any advantages or situations where the former is preferred?

Comment: late-binding? What do you mean? inheritance will still provide access to the parent-class namespace.

Comment: hmm yes I was confused ,let me clarify

Comment: inherit the class or declare it as global